# How to reproduce SmoothKernelDistribution[] for the bivariate case

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to reproduce the results of `SmoothKernelDistribution[]` for the bivariate case.

```
pts = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[0.8], 100];
Histogram3D[pts, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

```
p1 = Plot3D[
  Evaluate@PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[pts], {x, y}],
      {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]

k[u_] := 1/(2 \[Pi]) * Exp[-u.u/2]
k[h_, u_] := Det[h]^(-1/2)*k[MatrixPower[h, -1/2].u]
f[x_, y_, h_] := 
 With[{n = Length@pts}, (1/n) *
    Sum[k[h, {x - First@pts[[i]], y - Last@pts[[i]]}], {i, 1, n}]] // N

h = SmoothKernelDistribution[pts]["Bandwidth"];
bw = {{First@h, 0}, {0, Last@h}};
p2 = Plot3D[f[x, y, bw], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]

Style[Grid[{{p1, p2}}], ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

[image]

The plots differ a bit. It is as if my kernel density estimation has a larger bandwidth and things get smoothed out more than they should. Would you be so kind as to point me what I'm missing?

[Relevant ref: What do the options of SmoothKernelDistribution do?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4862/what-do-the-options-of-smoothkerneldistribution-do)

Comment: this might explain some of differences between the two pictures: your `f` places a kernel at every sample point,  but `SmoothKernelDesitribution` default value for the option `MaxMixtureKernels` not `All`, i.e it does not place a kernel at every data point.

Comment: Thank you @kglr for taking the time to comment. I tried with `SmoothKernelDistribution[pts, MaxMixtureKernels -> All]`, but the result is the same. Actually, it seems as if this is the default option: `SmoothKernelDistribution[pts, MaxMixtureKernels -> All] ==
SmoothKernelDistribution[pts]` returns True.

Comment: stathsik, you are right. I mis-interpreted the remark before the first example in [SmoothKernelDistribution>> Options>>MaxMixtureKernels](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html).

Comment: However, your comment was in the right direction; the options `MaxRecursion` and `InterpolationPoints` imply that `SmoothKernelDistribution[]` calculation is more sophisticated. Relevant: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4862/what-do-the-options-of-smoothkerneldistribution-do